# For integer partitions, why does $e(n)-o(n)=k(n)$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I denote by $e(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with an even number of *even* parts, $o(n)$ the number of those with an odd number of *even* parts, and $k(n)$ the number of those that are self-conjugate.

The claim is that $e(n)-o(n)=k(n)$.

By the answer in Aryabhata's comment, I know that 
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0}(e(n)-o(n))x^n=\prod_{i\geq 1}(1+(-1)^ix^i)^{-1}.
$$

I also know identity 
$$
\prod_{i\geq 1}(1+x^i)=\prod_{i\geq 1}(1-x^{2i-1})^{-1},
$$
so plugging in $-x$ yields and inverting gives
$$
\prod_{i\geq 1}(1+(-1)^ix^i)^{-1}=\prod_{i\geq 1}(1+x^{2i-1}).
$$
Does it somehow follow that this last expression above equals $\sum_{n\geq 0}k(n)x^n$ to get the result? Thank you.

(P.S. Is there a combinatorial argument for this equality? I'd like to see one if there is, but I'd be perfectly satisfied to just see the explanation of the sketch above. Either or.)

Comment: For $1^{st}$ question, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5025/partitions-with-even-number-of-even-parts-partitions-with-odd-number-of-even-p

Comment: Thanks @Aryabhata, seems like someone else had the same issue as me.

Comment: This question is identical to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92191/identity-involving-partitions-of-even-and-odd-parts), except that the formula given there has an extra factor $(-1)^n$ tacked onto one of the members of the equation. The cases $n=1$, $n=3$ show that such a factor is indeed necessary. The answers there contain a combinatorial argument I gave.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Maybe I'm mistaken, but in that question $p_E(n)$ is the number of partitions with an even number of parts, but here $e(n)$ is the number of partitions with an _even number of even parts_, and the same for $p_O(n)$ and $o(n)$.

Comment: @sprtof: Sorry about that, I overlooked, the notation looked so similar. Still the combinatorial proof I gave could inspire one for this case.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen That's quite all right, thanks for editing in the proper emphasis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, this is virtually the same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92191/identity-involving-partitions-of-even-and-odd-parts), even though this question considers only the parity of the number of *even* parts while that question does so for the parity of *all* parts (and throws in a factor $(-1)^n$). The connection is due to the fact that for any partition of $n$, the parity of its number of *odd* parts is necessarily the same as the parity of $n$ and therefore unalterable; therefore changing the parity of the number of parts always also changes the parity of the number of even parts. As a consequence one can prove this using the *same* bijection to cancel out non-contributing partitions. For your convenience I've edited my answer so as to apply directly to the current question, without needing translation.

Firstly, the Young diagram of a self-conjugate partition can be decomposed it into hooks with a diagonal square as corner, and can be reconstructed from the sequence of the (distinct odd) sizes of the hooks. As a consequence $k(n)$ equals the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct odd parts (and the generating series for the $k(n)$ is indeed $\prod_{i\geq 1}(1+x^{2i-1})$ as you guessed).

To equate this number to $e(n)-o(n)$, consider the following involution to match any partition of $n$ in the subset $S=p(n)\setminus  p_{DO}(n)$ of partitions that are not into distinct odd parts, with another element of $S$ with the opposite parity of its number of its even parts. For $\lambda\in S$, test the odd numbers $m=1,3,5,\ldots$ in order, considering the set of parts of $\lambda$ of the form $2^km$ with $k\in\mathbf N$. If the set is either empty or consists of a single part $m$, move on to the next odd number. Since $\lambda\in S$, there is some $m$ that is not skipped; stop at the smallest such $m$. Now take the maximal $k$ such that $\lambda$ has a part of size $2^km$. If this part is unique, then $k\neq0$ by the choice of $m$; break the part into two parts of size $2^{k-1}m$. Otherwise $\lambda$ has at least two such parts; glue them together to form a part of size $2^{k+1}m$. One readily checks that the partition $\mu$ so produced is in $S$, that this procedure is an involution on $S$, and that $\lambda,\mu$ always have opposite parities for the number of their even parts (any pair of equal-size parts does not contribute to this parity, regardless of their size).

So the elements of $S$ together produce a null contribution to $e(n)-o(n)$, while each element of $p_{DO}(n)$ is in $e(n)$ (as it has no even parts) and therefore contributes $1$ to this difference.

Comment: Thanks for translating the old answer!